# modification of the PERL script to consume less memory with higher speed

Tags: perl

I have written a script which compares multiple files and give the number of occurrence of each paragraph in each file. The script is working fine with smaller files but when applied to large files the program is stuck with no output. I need some help in modifying the script so that it can run on all files even if its very large. My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw( numeric );
my %seen;

$/ = "";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $value) = split ('\t', $_);

    my @lines = split /\n/, $key;
    my $key1 = $lines[1];

    $seen{$key1} //= [ $key ];
    push (@{$seen{$key1}}, $value);
}

my $tot;
my $file_count = @ARGV;
while ( my ( $key1, $aref ) = each %seen ) {
    $tot = 0;
    for my $val ( @{ $aref } ) {
        $tot += $val;
    }
    if ( @{ $aref } >= $file_count ) {
        print join "\t", @{ $aref };
        print "\tcount:". $tot."\n\n";
    }
}
```

I am providing sample file for understanding the situation better. data1.txt and data2.txt contains sample of data I have with me. I need to sum the occurrence of read in all the files if the second line of each read matches i.e the output the two files should be like shown in output.txt:

```
**data1.txt**

@NS500278
AGATCNGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACAACGTGATATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTC
+
=CCGGGCGGG1GGJJCGJJCJJJCJJGGGJJGJGJJJCG8JGJJJJ1JGG8=JGCJGG$G     1 :data1.txt

@NS500278
CATTGNACCAAATGTAATCAGCTTTTTTCGTCGTCATTTTTCTTCCTTTTGCGCTCAGGC
+
CCCGGGGGGGGGGJGJJJJJJJJJJJJJGJG$JJJJ$GGJ>JJJGGG8$CGJJGGCJ8JJ     3 :data1.txt

@NS500278
TACAGNGAGCAAACTGAAATGAAAAAGAAATTAATCAGCGGACTGTTTCTGATGTTATGG
+
CCCGGGGGGGGGGJGJJJJJJJJJJJJJGJG$JJJJ$GGJJJJJGGG8$CGJJGGCJ8JJ     2 :data1.txt

**data2.txt**

@NS500278
AGATCNGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACAACGTGATATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTC
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE6EEEEEAEEEAE/AEEEEEEEAE<EEEEA</AE<EE   1 :data2.txt

@NS500278
CATTGNACCAAATGTAATCAGCTTTTTTCGTCGTCATTTTTCTTCCTTTTGCGCTCAGGC
+
AAAAA#E/<EEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEA/EAAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EEEE/A6<E<EEE  2 :data2.txt

@NS500278
TACAGNGAGCAAACTGAAATGAAAAAGAAATTAATCAGCGGACTGTTTCTGATGTTATGG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEE/EEEAE6AE<EAEEAE     2 :data2.txt

**output.txt**

@NS500278
AGATCNGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACAACGTGATATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTC
+
=CCGGGCGGG1GGJJCGJJCJJJCJJGGGJJGJGJJJCG8JGJJJJ1JGG8=JGCJGG$G     1 :data1.txt    1 :data2.txt   count:2

@NS500278
CATTGNACCAAATGTAATCAGCTTTTTTCGTCGTCATTTTTCTTCCTTTTGCGCTCAGGC
+
CCCGGGGGGGGGGJGJJJJJJJJJJJJJGJG$JJJJ$GGJ>JJJGGG8$CGJJGGCJ8JJ     3 :data1.txt    2 :data2.txt   count:5

@NS500278
TACAGNGAGCAAACTGAAATGAAAAAGAAATTAATCAGCGGACTGTTTCTGATGTTATGG
+
CCCGGGGGGGGGGJGJJJJJJJJJJJJJGJG$JJJJ$GGJJJJJGGG8$CGJJGGCJ8JJ     2 :data1.txt    2 :data2.txt   count:4
```

I was trying to tie my hash to a file but unable to understand the concept. It would be of great help if anyone can explain the solution with a short example. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually you can't make your program run faster and use less memory at the same time. [Tying a hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBM::Deep::Cookbook#PERFORMANCE) will have significant impact on hash speed.

Comment: Why do you have `no warnings 'numeric'`?

Comment: @Borodin Because the code gives (beyond other warnings) `Argument "@NS500278 AGAT..." isn't numeric in addition (+) at x.pl line 24, <> chunk 2.`

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "_number of occurrence of each paragraph in each file_"?  How many times each paragraph occurs in all files? Can it be anywhere in a file? Can you please clarify?  (2) You build a monster hash, with the whole file in it -- that surely breaks for large files. (3) The counting is not correct -- the `+=` attempts to add the text.  (4) You split on tab `\t` -- where is that tab? Can't see it in posted examples.

Comment: I suggest -- don't turn off warnings, but find and eliminate reasons.

Comment: yes the hash breaks for large files. I am searching for a way out that the hash doesn't break for however large the file may be. The count of each paragraph is given in the second column of each file. I want to sum the count in all files only if second line of a paragraph matches.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the scale problem is of bigger concern as stated by the others in comments.  Tying the monster hashes to disk should be your next step on solving the problem.  Please consult [perltie](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html) and if you want an example, [this Perl Cookbook script](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/include/perl/ch14/userstats) should be useful.  If my memory serves, both keys and values in Berkeley DB can hold up to four gigabytes which should be more than ample for your need.  By the way, a nice side effect of this approach is that you can easily reuse the previous results.